# Como realizar leitura de um arquivo json local usando retrofit 2.0?

Tags: android, retrofit

Para finalidades de testes da API, preciso ler arquivos json que seriam meus responses nas requisições a API.

Pois bem, com o Retrofit 1.9 era possível implementar um "Client" e sobreescrever o método "execute()" para que fizesse a leitura do arquivo json localmente.

Com o Retrofit 2.0, é aceito apenas instâncias de OkHttpClient, não podendo mais fazer 'custom clients'.

Qual a melhor forma de contornar isso e fazer um mock para meu Client e fazer a leitura do arquivo Json localmente?

Comment: Teoricamente você não precisa usar o Retrofit para ler esse JSON localmente, basta apontar para o local. Daí basta usar somente os Parsers de JSON.

Answer (score 1):

O OkHttp que era opcional na versão 1.9 agora é requerido, além de integrado automaticamente. Isso trouxe diversos benefícios para a biblioteca.

Nesta versão, para fazer o parse do Json, você precisa declarar dependência do Gson Converter separadamente: `compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'`

Então utilizar o `addConverterFactory`. Veja exemplo do próprio site:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://api.nuuneoi.com/base/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
```

https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/retrofit-2.0/en